# Python program that finds most frequent word in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python
i have a text file
What I want the program to do is to find the 20 most used words and show them how many times they repeat (You can use Python's built-in functions and libraries.Do not use different libraries.)
What should I do next?

I could only do this part

```
FILE_NAME = 'file.txt'

wordCounter = {}

with open(FILE_NAME,'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:

        word_list = line.replace(',','').replace('\'','').replace('.','').lower().split()
        for word in word_list:
            if word not in wordCounter:
                wordCounter[word] = 1
            else:
                wordCounter[word] = wordCounter[word] + 1

for  (word,occurance)  in wordCounter.items(): 
    print(word,occurance)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, which is not a homework website. Questions should include an honest attempt to solve the problem. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Kindly provide what you have already tried so that we might be able to help you

Comment: okey  i edit it .

Comment: I think you are almost there james14.. Check if your indents are correct? You just need to sort the dictionary according to values

Answer (score 4):

You can use collections like this :

```
from collections import Counter

f= open("file.txt","r")
text =f.read()
#clean data
for char in '-.,\n':
    text=text.replace(char,' ')
#to lower
text = text.lower()
#to list
ls = text.split()
#most_common = 20
top_20 = Counter(ls).most_common(20)
#loop all most_common 
for x in top_20:
  print(x)
```

result is similar like this :

```
('dynamic', 3)
('as', 3)
('high', 2)
('level', 2)
('with', 2)
('for', 2)
('python', 1)
('is', 1)
('an', 1)
('interpreted', 1)
('object', 1)
('oriented', 1)
('programming', 1)
('language', 1)
('semantics', 1)
('its', 1)
('built', 1)
('in', 1)
('data', 1)
('structures', 1)
```